# Output of awk to variable is blank, but print is not

Tags: linux, awk, csh, can-bus

Lets say I have a directory that has the following files:

```
thing_one
thing_two
thing_three
```

I want to get an array of the second field if each file name is split on the underscore in csh. I have to use csh. Ex. one two three. I get the correct printout by using the following:

```
Is | awk -F_ '{ print $2 }
```

But, I want to assign the output to a variable. I tried using:

```
set output = "`ls | awk -F_ '{ print $2 }'`"
```

But, if I `echo output`, I get an array with `thing_one thing_two thing_three`. What am I missing? It's like the `awk` is being skipped.

Comment: I just noticed that the backticks didn't show in the post. There are backticks inside the double quotes on the set command.

Comment: I'm using a legacy system and I can't use anything else. That's why I specified I have to use csh. Switching is not an option.

Comment: You are beating a dead horse here. Trust me when I say I can't use anything else.

Comment: What is the `Is` command? Should that be `ls`?

Comment: There's no such thing as a legacy system that only has csh. Bourne shell predates C shell, and I don't think there are any systems without some form of Bourne shell. You don't have to use the same shell for scripting as you do for interactive use.

Answer (score 0):

In csh, double quotes turn off the meaning of special characters within them. Try without the quotes:

```
    set output=`ls | awk -F_ '{ print $2 }'`
```